# error with random.sample: raise NotImplementedError(" >= and <= don't work with 0.") NotImplementedError: >= and <= don't work with 0

Tags: python, for-loop, random, networkx

I have a problem with this code, I really dont understand why it cannot reach the second cycle of the most internal for:

```
def remove_random_links(A,E):
    rs = random.sample(A.edges, E)
    A.remove_edges_from(rs)

N = 30
L = [0,60,30,40,30,30,20,40]
rep = 15
d = []
g = []

for j in range(rep):
    R = nx.grid_graph(dim=[N,N])  
    _deg = []
    _gap = [] 
    for i in L:
        remove_random_links(R,i)
        A = nx.adj_matrix(R)
        L = nx.laplacian_matrix(R) 
        eigwd, eigv = LA.eigh(L.todense())
        eigw = np.sort(eigwd)
        eigw0 = eigw[0]
        eigw1 = eigw[1]
        eigw2 = eigw[2]
        eigw3 = eigw[3]
        gap = eigw2 - eigw1
        deg = eigw3 - eigw2
        _deg.append(deg)
        _gap.append(gap)
        print("meow")    
    d.append(_deg)
    g.append(_gap)
    print("M")

mean_deg = [np.mean(d[i]) for i in range(rep)]    
mean_gap = [np.mean(g[i]) for i in range(rep)]
std_deg = [np.std(d[i]) for i in range(rep)]
std_gap = [np.std(g[i]) for i in range(rep)]
```

It goes on its first for cycle (the one in j) and then into its first for cycle in i, it completes it and then it is not able to do the second one because of this error with the function remove_random_links(), which gives me the following error:

> > File "/Users/Sofia/Desktop/delta.py", line 23, in 
> >         remove_random_links(R,i)
>
> File "/Users/Sofia/Desktop/delta.py", line 9, in remove_random_links
>       rs = random.sample(A.edges, E)
>
> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/random.py", line 317, in sample
>       if not 0 <= k <= n:
>
> File
>   "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py",
>   line 322, in **ge**
>       "Comparing a sparse matrix with a scalar "
>
> File
>   "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py",
>   line 272, in _inequality
>       raise NotImplementedError(" >= and <= don't work with 0.")
>
> NotImplementedError:  >= and <= don't work with 0.

Comment: Is it possible for you to post the graph nodes and edges ? Also please post the whole code

Comment: I added the missing part of the code. The nodes and edges of the graph are the ones created by the networkx function R = nx.grid_graph(dim=[N,N])  
So they are like (0,0),(0,1),(0,2)...(0,N),(1,0).. and so on and their links are [(0,0),(0,1)]...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are using the same variable `L` twice, once here

```
L = [0,60,30,40,30,30,20,40]
```

Then reassigning it while iterating over it here

```
for i in L:
        remove_random_links(R,i)
        A = nx.adj_matrix(R)
        L = nx.laplacian_matrix(R)   #<--------change variable name
```

Use different variable names and that should do the trick, try this for instance

```
import random
from numpy import linalg as LA
def remove_random_links(A,E):
    print A.edges, E
    rs = random.sample(A.edges, E)
    A.remove_edges_from(rs)

N = 30
L_edges = [0,60,30,40,30,30,20,40]    #<--- changed it to L_edges
rep = 15
d = []
g = []

for j in range(rep):
    R = nx.grid_graph(dim=[N,N])  
    _deg = []
    _gap = [] 
    for i in L_edges:     #<--- changed it to L_edges
        remove_random_links(R,i)
        A = nx.adj_matrix(R)
        L = nx.laplacian_matrix(R) 
        eigwd, eigv = LA.eigh(L.todense())
        eigw = np.sort(eigwd)
        eigw0 = eigw[0]
        eigw1 = eigw[1]
        eigw2 = eigw[2]
        eigw3 = eigw[3]
        gap = eigw2 - eigw1
        deg = eigw3 - eigw2
        _deg.append(deg)
        _gap.append(gap)
        print("meow")    
    d.append(_deg)
    g.append(_gap)
    print("M")

mean_deg = [np.mean(d[i]) for i in range(rep)]    
mean_gap = [np.mean(g[i]) for i in range(rep)]
std_deg = [np.std(d[i]) for i in range(rep)]
std_gap = [np.std(g[i]) for i in range(rep)]
```